# Using bootstrap popover with jquery validation and knockout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, jquery-validate

I am working on using the Twitter Bootstrap popover to show validation errors from jQuery on a Knockout driven form.  I've got it showing the popover fine, but if I have to reload the data (such as on a fetch) while the popover is open, it stays there forever.

I have created a jsFiddle to demonstrate.  It can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bmccord/cmUtX/).

To display the problem, just start the Fiddle, click "Add Gift", then click "Submit" (the errors should pop up), then click "Reload"...the errors will stay.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be too simple just to hide the popups in your reload function?

```
self.reload = function() {
    $(".popover").hide();
    ......
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/unklefolk/cmUtX/5/

Comment: The drawback to that would be that if there is a popup somewhere else on the page that doesn't have anything to do with validation, it will get closed also.  I also don't know what that would do from a "memory leak" perspective since you aren't closing it in the "Bootstrap" way through calling the popover function.  However, that may be all I can do...

Comment: I agree that it isn't a perfect solution, Brian. I have had a bit of a mess around this morning. Basically it seems you need to revalidate your form after the reload. I tried adding a setTimeout after the observableArray has been repopulated in 'Reload' to revalidate the form but that didn't work. I also tried using the afterRender callback in the knockout templates with LIMITED success. You can see the results at http://jsfiddle.net/unklefolk/cmUtX/7/ You no longer have your nice popup messages and it validates as soon as a gift is added but maybe it may give you some inspiration! Good luck!

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer since I couldn't find a better one and this would work.  I eventually ended up abandoning this approach and also decided to use Knockout Validation instead of jQuery Validation.  The memory leak perspective scared me too much.